# Props is missing from props validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the following code which is being parsed by the linter eslint-plugin-react. It returns the warning:

> "product is missing in props validation"

while i declare **product** in **propTypes** at the bottom and that i pass it  to function. any idea ?

```
import React from 'react'

const ProductDesc = (props)=>({
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.product.headline}</h1>
        <img src={props.product.images[0].imagesUrls.entry[2].url} alt="Thumbnail large pic"/>
        <p>Yeah</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

ProductDesc.propTypes = {
  product: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default ProductDesc;
```

Comment: The linter might be confused because what you defined doesn't appear to be a valid React component. You either have to create a `class` or a use a function that returns something to render. Your function returns an object with a `render` method.

Comment: As you never check if *product* exists, you should at last use *React.PropTypes.object.isRequired* on *propTypes*.

Comment: allright I removed the render() which was messing up the component indeed

Answer (score -3, accepted):

syntax should have been

```
const ProductDesc = (props)=>{
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.product.headline}</h1>
        <p>Yeah</p>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you change?! Please describe your answer in more detail than just code.

Comment: I removed the render() method